# Rear Rack Ears for Dell PowerConnect 2824 Switch

Tags: rackmount, dell-powerconnect

I've been looking for a solution to mount the Dell switch from the back instead of the front, since we don't have a rack for switches yet.. My original thought was to find some special rack ears that are extended and reversed so that they can be still screwed in the front like they normally do, but be able to reach to the back and be screwed in the wall.

Have any of you found these reversed rack ears? Or maybe found a solution for something similar?

Comment: I'm having a hard time envisioning what you're describing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ewwhite Well, we know how the Dell switches only have 4 screw holes on the front-most side of the switch right? And the supplied rack ears only work to mount them from the front as you would expect from a regular rack. The thing is, we don't have a rack just for switches, so I want to be able to screw the switch on the wall, which would be easy if the switch had screw holes on the rear-most side. Is this better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your switch...

[image]

You want it on your wall...

Attach the provided rack ears to the front of the switch. Then use [a **wall-mount rack**](http://www.racksolutions.com/wall-racks.html), available in 1U, 2U and 3U options. Mount the switch flush to the wall with the ports pointing upward.

[image]

[image]

---

[This way, you can avoid something awful...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mij8B.jpg)

Comment: This is how it's done.

Comment: @joeqwerty [I much prefer this method...](http://i.imgur.com/4hWh1.jpg)

Comment: kce lol. @joeqwerty That's very ingenious! Actually, this will work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Carlo71 In that case get a patch panel and use short runs between the switch and the patch panel to get the "ports" down lower where they are more accessible. Ghetto but it'll work.